# Get ringtone of device and run it with activity

Tags: android, device, ringtone

How can I get ringtone of android device and set it in Activity (when activity start ringtone of device run automatiquelly )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Uri defaultRintoneUri = RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
    Ringtone defaultRingtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getActivity(), defaultRintoneUri);
    defaultRingtone.play();
```